# Laravel pagination does not work when using a group by and union

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Good evening everyone, I have a problem with laravel paginator, I have a query that consists of three requests that are the following

```
public static function getActu($user_id){
    //  1 select all the articles published by the shop followed by a user
    $res = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_folow_boutiques', 'user_folow_boutiques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('boutique', 'boutique.id', '=', 'user_folow_boutiques.boutique_id')
        ->join('type_article', 'type_article.boutique_id', '=', 'boutique.id')  
        ->join('article', 'type_article.id', '=', 'article.type_article_id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->select(DB::raw('article.*,article.created_at as date,null as nbrlik'));

    // 2 Select all the products that are liked by the users I followed
   $res2 =   DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_follow_user', 'user_follow_user.user_id_1', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('user_aime_article', 'user_follow_user.user_id_2', '=', 'user_aime_article.user_id')
        ->join('article', 'user_aime_article.article_id', '=', 'article.id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->select(DB::raw('article.*,user_aime_article.created_at as date, null as nbrlik') )
        ->distinct();
        // 3 Select all the products of the shop followed by the user and who have exactly 50 likes
    $res3 =   DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_folow_boutiques', 'user_folow_boutiques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('boutique', 'boutique.id', '=', 'user_folow_boutiques.boutique_id')
        ->join('type_article', 'type_article.boutique_id', '=', 'boutique.id')  
        ->join('article', 'type_article.id', '=', 'article.type_article_id')
        ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT article.id c_id, count(user_aime_article.id) as nbrlik FROM article JOIN user_aime_article on user_aime_article.article_id = article.id GROUP BY user_aime_article.article_id) e'),'article.id','=','e.c_id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->where('e.nbrlik','=',50)
        ->select(DB::raw('article.*,article.created_at as date,  e.nbrlik'))
        ->union($res)
        ->union($res2)
        ->groupBy('article.id')
        ->orderBy('date','desc')
        ->paginate(20)
        ->get();
        return $res3;
}
```

I need this information to be able to create a newsfeed in my client's site, and I need pagination to create an infinit scroll, but it does not work

I searched this problem on the net and I found that the use of the `paginate (x)` method with a groupby is not possible, and to work around this I must create the paging me and I tried what follows but it does not work

```
 $paginate = 5;
    $list_news = User::getActu(Auth::user()->id);// without  ->paginate(20);
    $slice = array_slice($list_news->toArray(), $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
    $result = new  Paginator($slice, 20);
```

Comment: You can mimic pagination by using `skip()` and `take()` like so: `$list_news = User::getActu(Auth::user()->id)->skip($paginate)->take(20)`, just increment the `$paginate` variable in each call.

Comment: thanks for your reply i'm going to test it

Comment: thanks it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static function getActu($user_id,$page){
    $paginate = 5;
    //  1 selectionnée tous les article publier par les shop suivi
    $res = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_folow_boutiques', 'user_folow_boutiques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('boutique', 'boutique.id', '=', 'user_folow_boutiques.boutique_id')
        ->join('type_article', 'type_article.boutique_id', '=', 'boutique.id')  
        ->join('article', 'type_article.id', '=', 'article.type_article_id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->select(DB::raw('article.*,article.created_at as date,null as nbrlik'));
       
    // 2 Selectionnée tous les produit amai par les utilisateur suivit Arevoir demain 
   $res2 =   DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_follow_user', 'user_follow_user.user_id_1', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('user_aime_article', 'user_follow_user.user_id_2', '=', 'user_aime_article.user_id')
        ->join('article', 'user_aime_article.article_id', '=', 'article.id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->select(DB::raw('article.*,user_aime_article.created_at as date, null as nbrlik') )
        ->distinct();
        // Selectioner tous les proiduit  des boutique suivi par le user qui ont 50 j'aime
    $res3 =   DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_folow_boutiques', 'user_folow_boutiques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('boutique', 'boutique.id', '=', 'user_folow_boutiques.boutique_id')
        ->join('type_article', 'type_article.boutique_id', '=', 'boutique.id')  
        ->join('article', 'type_article.id', '=', 'article.type_article_id')
        ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT article.id c_id, count(user_aime_article.id) as nbrlik FROM article JOIN user_aime_article on user_aime_article.article_id = article.id GROUP BY user_aime_article.article_id) e'),'article.id','=','e.c_id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
        ->where('e.nbrlik','=',50)
        ->select(DB::raw('article.*,article.created_at as date,  e.nbrlik'))
        ->union($res)
        ->union($res2)
        ->groupBy('article.id')
        ->orderBy('date','DESC')
        ->skip($paginate * ($page - 1) )->take($paginate)->get();
        return $res3;
}
```

Thanks to @N Mahurin

Answer (score 0):

union and Paginate cannot be used together
You can try this one.

```
        $res3 =   DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_folow_boutiques', 'user_folow_boutiques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('boutique', 'boutique.id', '=', 'user_folow_boutiques.boutique_id')
            ->join('type_article', 'type_article.boutique_id', '=', 'boutique.id')  
            ->join('article', 'type_article.id', '=', 'article.type_article_id')
            ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT article.id c_id, count(user_aime_article.id) as nbrlik FROM article JOIN user_aime_article on user_aime_article.article_id = article.id GROUP BY user_aime_article.article_id) e'),'article.id','=','e.c_id')
            ->where('users.id','=',$user_id)
            ->where('e.nbrlik','=',50)
            ->select(DB::raw('article.*,article.created_at as date,  e.nbrlik'))
            ->union($res)
            ->union($res2)
            ->groupBy('article.id')
            ->orderBy('date','DESC');
        $sql = $res3->toSql();

        $result = \DB::table(\DB::raw("($sql) as a"))->mergeBindings($res3)
            ->Paginate(10);
```